be mint doing sth, what does it mean?
From Youtube video, I heard two girls talking of a horse:


"Thorn(horse) was mint playing polo-cross".


From none-native speaker's understanding of my own, I took the word "mint" as "fresh", and I tried to find some usage of "mint doing sth" in various dictionaries, but got none.
So, I just wonder if you guys speak like that.

Please see Urban Dictionary. It's basically just used as a substitute for words meaning cool, class and ace.

If a coin was mint yesterday, it was born thus. Thorn was born to play polo. He was mint that way right from the start.

Help us to help you. What happened in the video? What were the characteristics of the horse (good, bad, old, young, fast, slow, graceful, awkward, etc)? How old were the girls, where were they from, how old was the video?

Green’s Dictionary of Slang suggests mint is generally used to refer to  something or someone that is good, cool or very nice:

mint adj.
(also mintox, mont, real mint)
[SE mint, unblemished]
(Can./US/UK teen) a general term of thorough approval.

1986    [Aus]   C. Bowles G’DAY 99: If something is [...] very good, it’s magic, top stuf, or mint, but often beaut or ripper.

1989    [US]    J. Doyle College Sl. Dict.  mint [CMU] really cool.

1997–2001       Online Sl. Dict.  mint adj 1. attractive, usually a male. (‘That guy is mint.’).

2007    [UK]    R. Milward Apples (2023) 29: Everyone looked mint without the crap baggy [school] shirts and that.




However, from the context, I think they were saying that Thorn was a fresh player in polo-cross.

@KevinCheng - Probably fresh but good anyway.

@KevinCheng: I think "mint = fresh, first-timer" would be bogglingly unlikely from an actual native Anglophone already familiar with mint = excellent

I haven't heard this usage for about 55 years.
